# Can't login after failed Catalina update, possibly because of both kernal panic AND low disk space?

Tags: crash, catalina

yesterday I started getting the message: "Your computer restarted because of a problem" so I took the first suggested solution and decided to upgrade from High Sierra to Catalina. Towards the end of the installation, it said that I needed an additional 900MB to install Catalina but then my computer restarted and Catalina seemed to have updated. However, upon entering my password to log in, computer crashes and the same "Your computer restarted..." message pops up.

In recovery mode, I am unable to recover from Time Machine backup, unable to use disk utility to repair the disk, and unable to reinstall Mojave-- the problem being that every time I try to "unlock" or "mount" Macintosh HD, my screen goes black and then I am taken back to the same login screen at which I am stuck on. When I try to reinstall Mojave, it states that I have 10GB available and need an additional 7GB, after which it then crashes and takes me back to the same login screen.

Tried CMD option P R to reset NVRAM. Nothing happened.

Can't boot into safe mode-- entering password to login simply causes the same crash / restart to the login screen.

In single user mode, attempting to mount the disk also causes crash so I am unable to delete any large files to free up disk space.

Additional Info: Late 2016 MacBook Pro; no external HD backup. Most important files are backed up so am okay with factory reset if all else fails (don’t know how to do that) but would prefer not to.

Got any solutions for me? I'm a desperate student :( Thanks for any insight!

Comment: If your backup is secure, look for how to do an erase install on the site here (or edit your mac model and year into the post and we’ll guide you through that). If you don’t have a backup or need one - let’s get that edited in so you can save your files. Sorry to non-answer comment, but it’s not really clear which way you need to go forward.

Comment: Hello, added the info (Late 2016 MBP 13’). How would I do a back up without being able to mount the disk? Thank you.

Comment: Internet recovery includes a terminal app and disk utility - both of which can mount and read the disk no matter what phase of Catalina install fails. It’s complicated, so it might be easier to target disk boot your mac and take it to a second computer to copy files off with Finder. Good news - your mac will boot to internet recovery so you can check on things